# Discord Bot Python Deleting Author's Message

Tags: python, discord

I made a small discord bot for some fun:

I want the author's messages to be deleted when Author run this command. But this does not work.

```
if message.content.startswith('Delete me.'):
    async for msg in client.logs_from(message.channel, message.author):
            await client.delete_message(msg)
```

Comment: Who told you logs_from accepts an author as the second positional argument? It's for the `limit`.

Comment: Hi @narae-choi don't forget to accept working answers, and upvote the answer to boost the contributor's reputation! If you've found your answer, then awesome! Also, don't forget, you can upvote helpful comments that add to your understanding as well!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at their [docs](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), `logs_from` takes a channel, along with additional arguments allowing you to 
filter which messages to retrieve.

So if you just wanted to delete all messages, you can do something like

```
async def on_message(message):
    NONSENSE_LIMIT = 999999999999
    if message.content.startswith('!delete'):
        async for log in client.logs_from(message.channel, limit=NONSENSE_LIMIT):            
            if log.author == message.author:
                await client.delete_message(log)
```

Which will delete all messages for a user that types in that command. Your bot must have the `manage messages` permission for that channel.

Note that the number of messages returned is limited, and here I just write down some arbitrary nonsense limit. If you want to be accurate, you would have to figure out how many messages there are in the channel somehow, and then use that as the limit.

I just looked up discord API in the last 5 minutes so I don't know if there's a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: But I have to say, the docs that I looked up were well-written and easy enough to set up a discord bot.

Comment: That only obtains the last 100 messages, of those it deletes the ones that's posted by the user. I think the OP wants all the author's messages deleted, and not just the messages the user sent within the last 100 messages. And no, there isn't a more efficient method since discord.py doesn't support it natively (if you want to re-write the whole logs_from chain of functions, then that will be a bit more efficient).

Comment: @abccd you're right, I just noticed it defaults to 100. Could probably hardcode a nonsense limit like 999999999, but that fails if a channel can have more messages than that. Otherwise I guess OP would have to count the total number of messages in the channel and use that as an upperbound.

Comment: IT REALLY WORK! Thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `client.logs_from(message.channel, message.author)`statement. `logs_from` accepts the following arguments: `logs_from(channel, limit=100, *, before=None, after=None, around=None, reverse=False)`. See [the API reference](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html). So you have two channel arguments where `logs_from` only accepts 1. Perhaps you intended `client.logs_from(message.author)` instead?

Comment: Thank you! but this `client.logs_from(message.author)` also did not work... `discord.errors.NotFound: NOT FOUND (status code: 404): Unknown Channel` how can I solve this?

Comment: @NaraeChoi You will need to put the correct channel name, I was just guessing. I can only see this snippet of your code so I don't know how you have your channels named.

Comment: @NaraeChoi ***read*** the acceptable parameters, the function ***does not*** accept an author argument anywhere. http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logs_from